# iOS app build failed when upgrading to capacitor 3

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am new to Capacitor and have upgraded a version 2.0 Capacitor iOS app to a version 3 of Capacitor. However, after doing the upgrade and running `npx cap sync ios` I get this error:

[image: Cap error]

Doing some research I saw on [capacitor's official upgrade docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0) that they recommend these instructions:

[image: official doc recommendation]

I went ahead and did this. Meaning I went into my ios/App/Podfile and made the recommended change which I think is the issue. However, every time i run `npx cap sync ios` it automatically sets the platform :ios back to '11.0' instead of the 12. I do not know what to do here to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated, otherwise I cannot build the app without downgrading back to Capacitor version 2.

Comment: Did you also update @calacitor/cli package to version 3?

Comment: No this is in my package.json. "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.7" Should I upgrade it?

Comment: yeah, all the capacitor packages versions should match

Comment: That was the issue and it solved my problem. Thank you!